# Why does a function get called before the line above it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and I just can't seem to wrap my head around why this doesn't work the way I want it to. I am using a html5 Javascript game engine called panda. I am attempting to pause my game and when I pause the game I would like to set PauseScreen to visible. Pause screen is the image I am attempting to display while the game is paused. game.system.pause(); is a function that is part of the engine. My question is why doesn't this work the way I want it to. I assume this is a question pertaining to Javascript and not panda; sorry if I'm wrong. Is this the result of Javascript's asynchronous nature?

```
pauseGameFunc = function (gmPsd){
    if (gmPsd === 0) {
        pauseScreen.visible = true;
        return game.system.pause();
    }
    else {
        pauseScreen.visible = false;
        return game.system.resume();
    }
}
```

Any help that you can offer me would be awesome. Sorry if I didn't give enough detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use var key word before pauseGameFunc  otherewise pauseGameFunc  will be a global variable

Comment: `pauseScreen.style.visibility= 'visible';` or `.style.display='inherit';`

Comment: i would recommend toggling a class on body and using inherited CSS to accomplish this, instead of touching discrete dom elements from all over your code. that makes it trivial to start showing something else on pause at a later point, or to use animation like fading instead of just show/hide.

Comment: @dandavis: Yeah, on `body` or at least on the container of the game. Big time.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "asynchronous nature". Some methods are designed to be asynchronous, but the language itself and its basic operations like variable assignments are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

`pauseScreen.visible = true;` if `pauseScreen` is an image element does nothing. If you want to hide it, it's:

```
pauseScreen.style.display = "none";
```

to show it again:

```
pauseScreen.style.display = "";
```

Your other option is the `visibility` property and the values `"visible"` and `"hidden"`. The difference is that with `display`, the hidden image doesn't take up any room in the layout. With `visibility` `"hidden"`, it still takes up room, it just doesn't show.